# MAMP:include_once 'model.php',failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller.php

```
<?php
include_once 'model.php';

class Controller {
 public $model;

 public function __construct()  
    {  
        $this->model = new Model();

    } 

 public function invoke()
 {
  //my code
}

?>
```

I put model.php in models But when i tried localhost:8888/innoshop/, i got error like this:

```
Message: include_once(model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Message: include_once(): Failed opening 'model.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/lib/php')
```

Comment: that's not how you load a model. check the documentation.